# how to launch only selected black berry project from eclipse?

Tags: installation, project, blackberry-simulator

I am new to work on black berry development.I am working with BlackBerry JDE 7.0.0 verision configured in to eclipse.In my eclipse I have created three project by using eclipse as follows:

```
            1.ServiceProject
            2.WorkonServices
            3.HelloWorld
```

When i debug the HelloWorld project then automatically remaning two also installing into black berry simulator.Here I would like to install HelloWorld project into simulator when i debug as black berry simulator.

How can i install selected project only into simulator?

please any body help me

Comment: you should clean the simulator and try running helloworld again Project>Blackberry>Clean Simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't know many things I'll try different solutions

1) First go to "Blackberry" in your toolbar and select "clean simulator"
Check the desired options and then over "HelloWorld" project rigth click and Debug.

The apps doesn't uninstall when you start debuging another proyect. Thats why I'm trying this first.

2) If 1) doesn't fix it. Try closing the unwanted projects (right click over the desired proyect and "close poject") and try again 1)

If both solutions doen's help you we'll have to know a bit more about the project configuration. Project type and that kind of stuff.